# Receiver has no segue with identifier 'goToDetail'

Tags: ios, swift

I've double-checked that my identifier is spelled correctly in the storyboard and that the segue is pointed in the right direction, but I keep receiving this error. Could someone take a look at my code to see if I'm missing something?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedData = tableData[indexPath.row]
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: selectedData)
    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            destination.vocab.text = sender as? String
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: can you add some UI of Identifier: "goToDetail"

Comment: can you show your storyboard?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I've included my storyboard

Comment: @tuyen le, I've included my storyboard

Comment: @heliona203 - move your navigationcontroller to infront of your tableviewcontroller and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it didn't work. I've also been getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on the `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {`  line of my AppDelegate along with the segue error. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @heliona203 - is this possible attach your project, or else plz update the screen shot

Comment: The problem is you performing a segue to a `UINavigationController`. You only perform segue from `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`, not `UINavigationViewController`. NavigationController should be the root of your storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`segue` can be used only with if you have a UINavigationController that will handle the navigation. You performing a segue to `UINavigationController`. `UINavigationController` should be at the root of your storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelectRowAt function change

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: selectedData)
```

To NavigationController Identifier (Note if you do not have identifier already set up in storyboard you will need to do that first)

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNavigationConrtoller", sender: selectedData)
```

And then change the prepareForSegue function to below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //check destination for segue is Navigation controller
    if let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
        // get hold of the first viewController.
        if let destination = navVC.viewControllers[0] as? DetailViewController {
            destination.vocab.text = sender as? String
            //all the other code you need
        }
    }
}
```